# How to give material look to the Search view widget

Tags: android, material-design, searchview, android-design-library, android-search

I am using Search view in the app and it was working fine. And I have implemented all of its method That I needed to implement in the App and it is working great and fine as expected.

**What I was doing:**

I was adding that in the action bar and in that I have implemented it as menu. So By clicking on its icon, it gets expanded and overlaps the App name that I really do not want to happen. So I thought to make a icon of search and put it in to the the action bar and when User will click on search icon it will show the Search view beneath the app title bar but there are few problems .

**Problems:**

1. When user click on the Imageview which shows exactly same icon as Search view , the search view gets appear beneath the actionbar,  but the problem is it appears with the search icon again and user has to click to that icon and then the search text field gets appeared. Where as I want that when I click on the icon in action bar the opened the search view should come in the layout.
2. I want to show underline or anything that should work like a material design on all devices as it is quite transparent and hard to see in the layout that where the search view has been appeared.

So I want just two things. The already opened search view, so that the user doesn't need to click again on the search view icon to open it and the outline around the search view so that it can easily be seen.